# Update of column used in the join

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update

I have a table where one column (`TXN_AMT`) was populated incorrectly. I am trying to update that column using aggregate data from the same table, based on the condition that for same account number on a given day if there are more than one transactions and Transaction amount is greater than or equal to sum of actual amount  then update Transaction amount with  actual amount. I tried using `MERGE` and a subquery, but Oracle rejects my update with "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated". My query:

```
MERGE INTO TXN W
USING (
  select TXN_AMT, ACCOUNT_NUM, TXN_DATE, sum(ACTUAL_AMT), count(1) 
  from TXN 
  where TXN_AMT is NOT NULL 
    and TXN_AMT > ACTUAL_AMT
  group by TXN_AMT, ACCOUNT_NUM, TXN_DATE
  having count(1) > 1 and TXN_AMT >= sum(ACTUAL_AMT)
) TBL
ON (W.ACCOUNT_NUM = TBL.ACCOUNT_NUM
  AND W.TXN_DATE = TBL.TXN_DATE
  AND W.TXN_AMT = TBL.TXN_AMT)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET W.TXN_AMT = W.ACTUAL_AMT;
```

I tried creating a separate table for the inner subquery, but this time Oracle rejected it with "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables".

How can I make this work?

Comment: The error clearly says you cannot update the column W.TXN_AMT when you are using this in `ON` clause. Please remove this column from on clause and give it a try.

Comment: I know that. But I need to consider the TXN_AMT in query

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic of the update you're trying to perform, nor the relevant part of the structure of the affected table.  Can you present an example?  And how is your table keyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do this in a MERGE statement by using the rowid in the join and analytic functions to do the sum and count, e.g.:

```
MERGE INTO txn w
USING (SELECT ROWID rid,
              txn_amt,
              account_num,
              txn_date,
              SUM(actual_amt) over(PARTITION BY txn_amt, account_num, txn_date) actual_amt,
              COUNT(1) over(PARTITION BY txn_amt, account_num, txn_date) actual_amt cnt
       FROM   txn
       WHERE  txn_amt IS NOT NULL
       AND    txn_amt > actual_amt) tbl
ON (w.rowid = tbl.rid AND tbl.cnt > 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    w.txn_amt = w.actual_amt
  where  tbl.txn_amt >= tbl.actual_amt;
```

Comment: Of course this supposes that (TXN_AMT, ACCOUNT_NUM, TXN_DATE) is a candidate key.  That seems likely based on the OP's query, but it is not altogether clear from the question.  If that holds, though, then this is a nice solution.

Comment: I am getting error ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated:

Comment: @Sid I've moved the problem join condition to the where clause of the update section. That should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Walk a cursor over the data and perform the updates in a loop:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (select TXN_AMT, ACCOUNT_NUM, TXN_DATE, sum(ACTUAL_AMT), count(1) 
                 from TXN 
                 where TXN_AMT is NOT NULL 
                   and TXN_AMT > ACTUAL_AMT
                 group by TXN_AMT, ACCOUNT_NUM, TXN_DATE
                 having count(1) > 1 and
                        TXN_AMT >= sum(ACTUAL_AMT))
  LOOP
    UPDATE TXN w
      SET TXN_AMT = aRow.ACTUAL_AMT
      WHERE w.ACCOUNT_NUM = aRow.ACCOUNT_NUM AND
            w.TXN_DATE = aRow.TXN_DATE AND
            w.TXN_AMT = aRow.TXN_AMT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. Since, it's a data patch PL/SQL block is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Update statement:

```
UPDATE TXN W
SET
    W.TXN_AMT = W.ACTUAL_AMT
WHERE
    ( W.TXN_AMT,
      W.ACCOUNT_NUM,
      W.TXN_DATE ) IN (
        SELECT
            TBL.TXN_AMT,
            TBL.ACCOUNT_NUM,
            TBL.TXN_DATE
        FROM
            TXN TBL
        WHERE
            TBL.TXN_AMT IS NOT NULL
            AND TBL.TXN_AMT > ACTUAL_AMT
        GROUP BY
            TBL.TXN_AMT,
            TBL.ACCOUNT_NUM,
            TBL.TXN_DATE
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
               AND TBL.TXN_AMT >= SUM(TBL.ACTUAL_AMT)
    );
```

Cheers!!